Full Attack and Mythic Haste
Does Mythic Haste allow making a regular move and Full Attack in the same turn?
https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Haste
Mythic Haste gives bonus move action, for a total of two move actions. Regular case Full Attack effectively uses Move Action + Standard Action (doesn't prevent swift, immediate and free actions). Since we got bonus move action on top of that, this should be possible, correct?
DISCLAIMER: My usual preference is RAW answers but I'm well aware Mythic Ruleset, however great, isn't as well thought, edge-case-proofed and doesn't consider a lot of things so if RAW fails I'm fine with "good practice" answers.

Probably not.
A Full Attack is a "Full-Round Action":

If you get more than one attack per round because your base attack bonus is high enough (see Base Attack Bonus in Chapter 3), because you fight with two weapons or a double weapon, or for some special reason, you must use a full-round action to get your additional attacks.

A Full-Round Action is defined as:

A full-round action requires an entire round to complete. Thus, it can’t be coupled with a standard or a move action, though if it does not involve moving any distance, you can take a 5-foot step.

This is more restrictive than saying it consumes a Standard and Move action. You cannot complete a Full-Round Action and use Mythic haste's Move action. This interpretation also prevents abuse such as getting two Full-Round Actions.
However, it is within reasonable power for a Mythic game GM to allow you to take the Move action and Full Attack. Many if not most TTRPG enthusiasts agree that melee martial are severely handicapped in the Pathfinder 1e ruleset, compared to basically all other play styles. I would still recommend against allowing two Full-Round actions, under any circumstances, personally.

Shame on me for not finding it before asking my question but here it goes...
Reference: Is Mythic Haste really one of the best mythic spells ever?
As it stands, current interpretation is that move action granted by Haste, Mythic is in addition to the full round as used by full attack action, not a part of it, thus allows making move action and a full attack action in the same turn. "Specific beats general" also agrees with this interpretation since full round action is a general term and bonus movement action don't really interferes with that, being it's own thing.
I'm also upvoting the accepted answer in the reference question.

I have to disagree somewhat; the accepted answer to the linked duplicate doesn't provide any evidence for its conclusion other than "that's what people are doing"
